# How to interpret AJAX to PHP communication?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Consider this snippet

```
// data.php
<?php
    function getDBData(){
        //log the call
        $fetchedData = myDbCode.fetchData();
        return $fetchedData;
    }
    echo getDBData();
?>

// html file
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getDBData = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php"
        }).done(callback);
    }
    var dbData = <?php echo json_encode(getDBData()); ?>
    getDBData(function(data) {
        dbData = data;
    })
</script>
```

Where does the code begin executing from and what's calling what? "getDBData" is referenced four times.

1) Is the reference inside json_encode getting called first and is that the PHP function it's calling?

2) How does it know in which file to find it?

3) It seems that on the last set of lines in the script, getDBData is getting called a second time, this time passing it's being passed another function (from Javascript), but what's the "data" variable refer to?

4) Why is the result of that function being assigned to "dbdata". It doesn't seem to get used anywhere. This could simply because it's only a snippet and it's used elsewhere.

5) Why is the function(callback) being assigned to the same name as the PHP function?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it is the PHP function. But that's not the first time the function gets called. The first time is `echo getDBData();`.

2) The function must be defined in the current PHP file or any included/required PHP file. PHP will not look for the definition outside of that. For this snippet to work, at the top of the "html file" (which would actually have to be a PHP file), there would likely be a line like this: `<?php require('data.php'); ?>`. But then it would be echoing the output... so perhaps it would just be easier to copy and paste the function definition into this file? This snippet needs some work, I think.

3) First of all, that call to `getDBData` is the first and only call to the *javascript* function by that name. The javascript getDBData function passes along whatever parameter it gets to that jquery promise-looking thing (done). That function expects a parameter that is a function. And the function provided to done() will get passed several parameters, if you choose to accept them. In this case, the function being passed in will accept the first parameter, which is the data obtained from the AJAX request. Whoever wrote this code thoughtfully chose to call that parameter "data," but any arbitrary name would be valid.

4) You're right, it's not being used anywhere in the snippet.

5) Because whoever wrote this wanted the code to be as confusing as possible? We can only speculate. I mean, they chose to include jquery to do a simple AJAX request, can we truly expect the author to have any sense? But seriously, there's no need to use the same name for both.